# Liquid Fertilizer

Tags: science-based, creature-design, avian

In this [post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/215302/90300) I asked if it would be possible for a species of bird to create saliva capable of curing animals (even those of other species) and stimulating plant growth. The answers and comments hinted that this would be scientifically impossible, only if the bird uses magic. So, I decided to divide this bird species into two: a farmer species and a healer species. In this post I will focus on the farmer species.

Well, the details are as follows: this species produces a liquid that comes out of its mouth along with saliva (for short, I'll just call it "saliva" from now on), this saliva is poured into seeds and plants to stimulate their growth . The bird's diet is based on fruits, flowers and herbs. This bird has a "bag" that it can use to carry water and then pour it into the plant to water it. That said, I ask: **how could an animal produce this liquid?**

Remember to reveal these things more also to answer the question:

- In my world, this species arose through creation, not evolution, that is, gods created this species, it did not evolve until it reached this state. I think this breaks down some barriers;
- You can't depend on magic to produce this liquid, there has to be a scientific explanation for it.

Comment: Does the saliva needs to be actually poured? I see no reason for the bird to acquire or maintain the habit of simply drooling or barfing on new seeds. Alternative: the birds acquire needed micronutrients from the cuticle of the seeds, but vomits the seeds after, covered in a mucus that can be "engineered" to produce the transformations you want.

Comment: How is that going to stimulate the growth of plants after the seeds germinate? Salivating at least the bird nourishes the plant even after germinating.

Comment: I can design a solution for after the seeds germinate, if an initial ingestion/barfing at seed stage is allowed. If not, it doesn't worth the time.

Comment: Taking a look at plant hormones could help you out a lot on figuring this out.

Answer (score 5):

**You make such a liquid yourself!**

[image: green grass]

https://anrcatalog.ucanr.edu/pdf/8255.pdf

Yes you do you wondrous creature!  I do too.  Also the dog, that used its growth-potentiating liquid on the depicted grass.  Marvel at its lush greenness!  The grass next door is jealous and hopes the dog will come back with more.

A biological liquid containing nitrogen, phosophorus and other minerals needed for plant growth is no fiction.  Urine can serve fine in that regard.  It is fertilizer.    Perhaps your bird saliva is such that concentrations are never so great as to "burn" the plants so treated as urine can sometimes do.

Comment: Is it possible for saliva to be even more efficient than urine?

Comment: For example, if a plant takes 9 months to grow and bear fruit, with this saliva it would take 6-7 or a little less. It won't be something miraculous that makes the plant grow immediately, but it will go faster than normal.

Comment: Heck ya.  It is saliva as Miracle Grow.  You could have some antifungal stuff in the drool too.

Comment: And the fruiting? Would it also be stimulated?

Comment: Here you go, Wiz.  https://organicgrowersschool.org/gardeners/library/basic-plant-nutrition/

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to the "healer" birds...

Perhaps a type of bacteria, such as bacteriophages, are active in bird saliva because their water source is densely filled with this.

Consider the presence of [bacteriophages in the Ganges river](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/Testing-the-waters-Labs-study-healing-powers-of-Ganga/article14416817.ece), and their scientific contribution to giving the water "healing properties".

More specifically,

> one hypothesis is that the waters of the river contain bacteriophages
> — viruses that replicate within bacteria and are toxic to them.

Dr. Mayilraj [from another source](https://www.newindianexpress.com/lifestyle/2016/sep/24/It%E2%80%99s-scientifically-validated-now-Ganga-water-is-%E2%80%98holy%E2%80%99-1524518.html) explains,

> the fresh water sediments from the Ganges house several novel viruses,
> which were never reported earlier. These bacteriophages are active
> against certain clinical isolates, or viral strains and can be used
> against multi-drug resistant or MDR infections.